# Isn't being polite a good practice at Stack Overflow anymore?

Tags: discussion

Just curious. My question was edited and the phrase "Thanks in advance :)" was removed. Just this phrase, no more, nor less.

Should I no longer thank anyone here? Just impersonal Q&A?

Edit:
Well, sorry for duplicating the question. Just want to add a few thoughts to that (since it's discussion, I think I can do that, right?)
If you're comparing this to wiki, you might notice, that the wiki is made by users ... and that's pretty much all that's pointing us, that there're a huge community standing besides it.

On the other hand, here we have a lot of people, with faces, names, questions and answers history. I feel like I'm talking to an experts, when I'm asking a question (and definately, not like I'm reading an encyclopedia).

And here goes 2 main questions:
1. What is the motivation for being active here? Getting few more "stars" for the answer and a new achievement for editing 100k posts?
2. Is "check" near to question is all that you expect to get as reward? Ok, I agree, answering to questions is also a way of learning or keeping yourself "in a good shape" ... but isn't knowing that the person on other side is feeling thankful for the help is a good addition to that?

Why shouldn't we be named as "StackOwerflowUser1234567"? If this is not for providing help from one people to another, but an soulless "article-book".

P. S. Please, understand me right. I spent here a lot of time (mostly reading, tho) and I love this site. I'm commenting here only because I want it to remain good and get even better.

Comment: Long story short: yep, leave such content out of your questions. We'll assume you're polite and thankful. ;)

Comment: You can - and should - thank people by up voting and accepting answers.

Comment: You can also leave comments under a good answer, saying "Thanks for your great answer! This is a very good explanation!" .....I do it all the time.

Answer (score 21):

When you ask a question on Stack Overflow, you are creating a wiki.

The wiki was initially authored by you, but its purpose is twofold.

1. Get you an answer to your problem
2. More importantly, make the Internet better

The second goal is served in a much cleaner fashion by removing superfluous introductions and signatures.